# Webpart disabled! error!

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

1. In this image i am not able to press the webpart button to upload a webpart it does'nt mather which webpart , webpart button is disbled!
2. When trying to Delete an existing webpart i get the following error message like in image 3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try go to this url:

```
http://YOURSITE/_layouts/spcontnt.aspx?PageView=Shared&url=%2fYOUR_PAGE_WITH_WEBPARTS%3fPageView%3dShared%26InitialTabId%3dRibbon.WebPartPage%26VisibilityContext%3dWSSWebPartPage
```

just replace YOURSITE and YOUR_PAGE_WITH_WEBPARTS (e.g. default.aspx) in the URL. It should redirect you to the mgmt page with webparts, where you should be able to delete the problematic one.

Comment: my site is http://wingtip:49074/ what do u mean with your_page_With_webparts?

Comment: do u mean this page? http://wingtip:49074/SitePages/Show%20News.aspx?WikiPageMode=Edit&InitialTabId=Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab&VisibilityContext=WSSWikiPage

Comment: I use URL in this format when I want to manage homepage: http://localhost:5555/_layouts/spcontnt.aspx?PageView=Shared&url=%2fdefault.aspx%3fPageView%3dShared%26InitialTabId%3dRibbon.WebPartPage%26VisibilityContext%3dWSSWebPartPage

Comment: i dont get it to work

Comment: NVM, try to solve problem with your webpart first: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_vbnet_server_error_potentially_dangerous.htm Or delete webpart content in sharepoint folder (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\...)

Comment: No sure where you page is going to, but the correct way to get into web part edit mode is to append ?contents=1 to the end of your URL.

Answer (score 1):

Open the web part page in view mode, not edit mode. Then add this to the URL

?contents=1

So, if your URL for the page is

```
http://MyServer/MyLibrary/MyWebPartPage.aspx
```

change it to

```
http://MyServer/MyLibrary/MyWebPartPage.aspx?contents=1
```

This will show you a page where web parts on the page are listed and you can select individual web parts and delete them.

Comment: yes i get it but i can not still not add any webpart to my page

Comment: The idea here is to give you another approach to delete the trouble web part, since you get an error message when you edit the web part page and try to delete it there.

Comment: i solved it in webconfig